# How to make `dotnet add` work with Central Package Management?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to add a package to a dotnet project. The solution is using Central Package Management https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management, where all package version are defined in the `Directory.Packages.props` file.

When I run `dotnet add`, the .csproj is updated to contain:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />`

When I run `dotnet restore`, I get an error, because the PackageReference should not contain a version.

```bash
# Create solution
dotnet new sln --name MySolution
mkdir src
dotnet new console -o src/Sample.Console
dotnet sln add src/Sample.Console/Sample.Console.csproj

# Create the Directory.Packages.props file for Central Package Management
$CPM_FILE=@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageVersion Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
'@
echo $CPM_FILE > Directory.Packages.props

# Add package - this updates the .csproj and specifies the package version
dotnet add src/Sample.Console  package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

# dotnet restore fails because it doesn't like the version on the PackageReference
dotnet restore

> Determining projects to restore...
demoapp/src/Sample.Console/Sample.Console.csproj : error NU1008: Projects that use central package version management should not define the version on the PackageReference items but on the PackageVersion items: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. [demoapp/MySolution.sln]
  Failed to restore demoapp/src/Sample.Console/Sample.Console.csproj (in 31 ms).
```

Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to make `dotnet add` work nicely with the Central Package Management (make it not add the version in the PackageReference in the .csproj, but rather add/use the version from `Directory.Packages.props`). I can obviously manually update the .csproj file and remove the Version, which will make the restore work, however I'm using this `dotnet add` in a Dockerfile for building and running some tests.

```bash
dotnet --version
7.0.102
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I'm facing. I was expecting an option  for the `dotnet add <package>` but there aren't any options.
All what I do is just select the target project then add the reference and then move the newly added package to the `Directory.Packages.props` file (as <PackageVersion>) and add <PackageReference> in the target project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dotnet 7.0.2xx seems to fix the issue and is released.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11807#issuecomment-1401342849